error when connecting the board black pill to the ide cubeide and cubeprogrammer
need to connect stm32 black pill board to cubeide and cubeprogrammer on linux mint
I tried to connect to cubeide but it gives the error “Error in final launch sequence:
Failed to execute MI command:
target remote localhost:86532
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:86532: Connection timeout expired.
Failed to execute MI command:
target remote localhost:86532
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:86532: Connection timeout expired.
localhost:86532: Connection timeout expired.” and also to cubeprogrammer but also error ”Error: No STM32 target found! If your product embeds Debug Authentication, please perform a discovery using Debug Authentication
”
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

It's trying to connect to the debugger. Black pill has no debugger.
